# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR on WordPress multisite

Tags: wordpress, http-error, openlitespeed

When I trying to customize any page in any site I get this error in the console of the browser inspector.
and the screen gets interrupt..

please see image below...

I'm running this WordPress multisite instance on a OpenLiteSpeed Web server.

[image: The error that i get in the console]

[image]

Please help me out what is causing this error I spent hours searching for solution and no results.

Comment: Better to ask this question in openlitespeed forum or community instead of StackOverflow.  It could be due to multiple possible reasons, e.g. an outdated browser or network security .. etc.

Comment: thanks for your replay, I didn't now where exactly the error is so I'm really confused in which community should I post this issue.

Comment: Try https://forum.openlitespeed.org/

Answer (score 1):

There are several reasons, one of them has to do with the text being too large on the same line. In my case it was a text coming directly from the database, I just changed the text through the database and everything was fine.

From what I've researched, there are also other reasons, such as file size limit and even the server with full storage.